# Unfaithful irreps of $S_n$ with dimension greater than one

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

The irreducible representation of $S_4$ corresponding to the partition $2+2$ is *two*-dimensional and *un*faithful. Are there other unfaithful irreps of $S_n$ with dimension greater than 1?

Comment: Hint: What do you know about normal subgroups of $S_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of a representation is a normal subgroup, and of course the representation is the result of lifting the representation of the quotient.  Since we know the only normal subgroups of $S_n$ are $1,A_n,S_n$ (except $n=4$ having $V\lhd S_4$ too) and the quotients $S_n/A_n\cong C_2$ is abelian, the only case left is $S_4/V\cong S_3$ which has only one irrep of degree >1. So there are no other non-faithful irreps of $S_n$ of degree >1.